# Auto increment it's not working

Tags: mysql

I have a problem on my website with auto increment and I can't find a way to fix it...

It works with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `password` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `loginhash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_level` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `random` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
    `email` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `language` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `style` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `joined` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `lastconnect` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `lip` bigint(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `downloaded` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
    `uploaded` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
    `avatar` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `pid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `flag` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `topicsperpage` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '15',
    `postsperpage` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '15',
    `torrentsperpage` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '15',
    `cip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `time_offset` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `temp_email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `flags` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '7345036',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
    KEY `id_level` (`id_level`),
    KEY `pid` (`pid`),
    KEY `cip` (`cip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

But it doesn't work with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `password` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `loginhash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_level` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `random` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
    `email` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `language` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `style` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `joined` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `lastconnect` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `lip` bigint(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `downloaded` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
    `uploaded` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
    `avatar` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `pid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `flag` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `topicsperpage` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '15',
    `postsperpage` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '15',
    `torrentsperpage` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '15',
    `cip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `time_offset` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `temp_email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `flags` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '7345036',
    `rank_switch` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    `old_rank` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
    `timed_rank` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `seedbonus` decimal(5,1) NOT NULL,
    `on_forum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `on_topic` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `custom_title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `invites` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `invited_by` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `invitedate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `donor` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    `banfromforum` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
    KEY `id_level` (`id_level`),
    KEY `pid` (`pid`),
    KEY `cip` (`cip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Doesn't work, how? What happens?

Comment: With the one that I said it works I can create an account and the second that I need doesen't says username exists so I'm guessing is because of the increment

Comment: Its probably you already have that username in the table

Comment: No I don't also I've tryied with other username and still not working

Comment: Make sure you are inserting a value into the username field.  Perhaps you are not and it is inserting the default value.  Otherwise you are inserting a username that already exists.

Comment: Yes, I'm inserting the username thru php... $user   = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["user"]);

What strange is with the first table works

Comment: Are you sure the username value is being correctly inserted into the second table in your code? I would remove the DEFAULT clause from the username column - you're otherwise requiring that column to be unique, so the DEFAULT would only ever work once anyway. Not much point, and could hide other issues.

Comment: Yes it's corectly it's not the code the problem is the table... with the first one works but with the second not, also I've looked into the apache error log and there are no errors related to the file that insert's the username